# Can't import pytorch

Tags: python, anaconda

I am trying to import pytorch but I get an error that module does not exist. I installed via anaconda, and the folder "pytorch-0.1.12-py35_2cu80" exist in anaconda3/pkgs folder. why does it not recognize that it is there? should I rename this folder?

-Rik

```
/home/rik/anaconda3/bin/python /home/rik/PycharmProjects/self_driving_car/self_driving.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/rik/PycharmProjects/self_driving_car/self_driving.py", line 18, in <module>
    import pytorch
ImportError: No module named 'pytorch'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Add some more details about the errors you get to your question.

Comment: I added the traceback, but it just says no module. I'm a little bit clueless as to how things work in conda with dependencies and finding the package.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The command to import pytorch is

```
import torch
```

not

```
import pytorch
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems the module `pytorch` is not installed.

First make sure your using anaconda's `python` and not the system one.

To install `pytorch` via `conda` do

`conda install pytorch torchvision -c soumith`

or via pip

For python3

```
pip install http://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu75/torch-0.1.12.post2-cp35-cp35m-linux_x86_64.whl 
pip install torchvision
```

For python2

```
pip install http://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu75/torch-0.1.12.post2-cp27-none-linux_x86_64.whl 
pip install torchvision
```

dont install the CUDA version if you dont have Nvidia GPU on your machine that supports.